# Android app stop after firebase integration

Tags: java, android

-----Its not working at phone ... but stil work in Nox emulator , Tabs ... 
after install app stop ... show Unfortunately app has stoped ... I added json file also and Fingerprint (SH1) ... How i fix it ? Please give me some way to fixed it ----

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 25
  buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.nil_akash.laws"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
  }
  buildTypes {
    release {
      minifyEnabled false
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
  packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    //exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    //exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    //exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    //exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    //exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    //exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    //exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    //exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    //exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    //exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
  }
}

dependencies {
  compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
  androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
  })
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'

  //database depedency
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.8.0'
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.8.0'
  compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.4.1'
  compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-parent:2.5.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

dependencies {
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
  classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try enabling google play services in ur another emulator.firebase dont work without google play services.as per your code try this:
project level build file

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

for app level build:

```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mrnobody.firebasetutorial"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner         "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),  'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }


        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'

    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-    core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```